# How to retain date and time in a variable?

Tags: c#, android, datetime, visual-studio-2012

i have the following code:

```
  Button schedend = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonschede);
        schedend.Click += schedend_Click;



    }


    void schedend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DateTimePickerTemplate);
        dialog.SetTitle("Pick date and time");
        TimePicker tp = FindViewById<TimePicker>(Resource.Id.timePicker1);
        Button butadd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonadd);
       //tp.SetOnTimeChangedListener(onTimeChangedListener: retain());
        // tp.SetIs24HourView(new Boolean(true));
        butadd.Click += butadd_Click;
        //tp.SetIs24HourView(true);
        dialog.Show();
    }
    private void retain()
    {

    }
    void butadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        EditText edittxt = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editschstart);

        edittxt.Text = e.ToString();

    }
```

I have a custom dialog, with a date and timepicker

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:text="Add"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonadd" />
        <Button
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttoncancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried different methods, but to no succes, how can i retain the date and time that was set,retain it in a variable,and when i click the add Button from dialog,i save them in an edittext? I am new to this and need some help.Thx

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm understanding you question correctly. If you mean to simply get the data that the user set using the `TimePicker`, you can simply use the built in methods such as `tp.getCurrentHour()` or `tp.getCurrentMinute()`. There's a full list of the methods you can use on the `TimePicker` in the Android documentation found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html). As for setting that data into an `EditText`, you just need to `edittxt.setText(yourVariableHere)`. In this particular situation you may want to consider making your `TimePicker` accessible from the rest of the class such as making it a private instance variable in the `Activity`. That way you can set the `EditText` to whatever you want from the `TimePicker`.

Comment: Sry if i wasnt very clear,i want to take both,time and date(set by user),to set the edittext.

Comment: I believe the `TimePicker` is only the time, if you want an interface for the date, you can use a `DatePicker`. I'm not sure how to be more clear in my answer about how to retrieve the time that the user selected in the `TimePicker`; unless I'm not understanding your question fully.

Comment: I solved, the problem, i take mydatePIcker.toShortdateString()+" "+mytime.currentHour+":"+mytimepicker.currentMinute, and set it in a textbox! Thx ! :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I knew that it must have been some methods you could call from the picker objects.